# Dismiss a map view (MKMapView) in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, mkmapview

In a little `iOS` app using `SwiftUI`.
There is a map and a button which is meant to dismiss the map.

I first read this tutorial: [Advanced MKMapView with SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/advanced-mkmapview-with-swiftui) to know how to handle `MKMapView` in `SwiftUI`, and it is working. Here is the code for the MapView:
(Code almost entirely based on the tutorial mentioned above)

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        appLocalizeMap(mapView)
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: MapView

        init(_ parent: MapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }

    // User added code.
    func appLocalizeMap(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
        let locatSide = 1000.0
        mapView.isRotateEnabled = false
        mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: centerCoordinate,
                                            latitudinalMeters: locatSide,   longitudinalMeters: locatSide)
    }

    func dismiss() { // Not currently working ...
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Then I need to set the button to dismiss the map. This is where I am in trouble.

Below is the code, where I show the map and I set a button on top of it.
It looks fine, but only looks. Nothing is working. After searching the net and reading some more, I have the feeling I am not setting the button where I should be. Beside I don't know where (presumably in the code of MapView) I am supposed to have the code making the map disapear.

```
ZStack {
    MapView(centerCoordinate:
        Binding(get: {CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                            latitude: self.refSpot.userLatitude,
                            longitude: self.refSpot.userLongitude)},
                set: {newValue in}))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    
    Button(action: {
        print("Dismiss Map")
    }) {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "Back.png")!)
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

What I have found in other documents relative to dimissing a `View` doesn't seem to apply to the `MapView` here.
Any relevant tip will be very much appreciated.

To make things clearer if needed. Here is the app at start:

[image]

The button **Open a map** works as expected. When tapped it brings this:

[image]

The problem lies in the cross shaped button at the top left of this last picture. This button should make the map and itself disappear, going back to the first image.

Using this code (modified):

```
Button(action: {self.showingMap.toggle()}) {
    Text("Open a map")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .padding()
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
            .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 4))
}.sheet(isPresented: $showingMap) {
    ZStack {
        if self.showMap {
            MapView(centerCoordinate:
                Binding(get: {CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                                latitude: self.refSpot.userLatitude,
                                longitude: self.refSpot.userLongitude)},
                        set: {newValue in}))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
        
        Button(action: {
            self.showMap.toggle()
        }) {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "Back.png")!)
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hitting the cross button now brings this view:

[image]

Where though the map itself is gone, the cross button is still there and the top image is not coming back.

Comment: I agree with Asperi. You are using the MapView inside another View. The only option is to show it depending on a condition, as you can not call dismiss function from parent view. Map View is not acting as modal / navigation link/ sheet view here, so it does not make any sense to use presentationMode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant this...

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var showMap = true

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if showMap {
                MapView(centerCoordinate:
                            Binding(get: {CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                                        latitude: self.refSpot.userLatitude,
                                        longitude: self.refSpot.userLongitude)},
                                    set: {newValue in}))
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.showMap.toggle()
            }) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "Back.png")!)
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion you make. It is doing something, but not yet what I want.
I already have a working button to make the map appear. The issue I have is with the button to make the map disappear. I edited the post after following your tip, adding three screenshots and appropriate comments. I also included a bit more code.
Please take a look to see the details.

Comment: I finally made it work, following on your suggestion.
First moving a closing curly brace to make the cross button disappear along with the map; then replacing your showMap by the showingMap which was already in my code but iniatized to false.